# Pay for Apple Developer Program from account money

Tags: developer-program

I'm member of the iOS developer program. During this month it will expire. I have about $200 on account. Is it possible to pay from this money without cashing out for the developer program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developer account credit, Apple ID account money or any local way to add money to those accounts (like Paypal etc) are invalid for the Developer Program.

The one and only way to pay is by credit card.

UPDATE: digged our mail archive and found a reference to this:

> Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2012 15:17:48 -0700 (PDT)
>
> From: devprograms@apple.com
>
> Subject: Re: Other
>
> Re: Other
>
> Hello ****,
>
> This is Jacob with Apple Developer Program Support.  Thank you for contacting us regarding payments of the iOS Developer Program.
>
> We only accept credit card payments for Apple Developer products.  I apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you.>
>
> For more information, you can refer to the Developer Support Center, which I have included at the link below for your convenience.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/purchase-and-next-steps.html
>
> I hope that this information has been helpful to you, but if you have any additional questions, please do not hesitate to contact us.  You can contact us by phone at 1 (800) 633-2152 from Monday through Friday from 9:00AM to 7:00PM CST.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Jacob
>   Apple Developer Program Support